# Grow a div to the left

Tags: html, css

Is this even possible? The basic setup is a sidebar on the right with div elements in it.
Clicking one of these elements would add a "popout" div, that should be displayed left of the clicked element. The popout contains a variable number of buttons.
I'd like to style it using only CSS, so i can just add the correct HTML elements from my script and have the stylesheet do the layout.

- I've attepmted the popout inside the sidebar element, positioned absolutely, but then I cannot make the sidebar element itself scale to be at least as tall as the popout. (The sidebar elements are usually shorter in height than the popout).
- I tried putting the popout before the element, and using position absolute, but for some reason the popout will not get wider if i add more buttons, and instead overflows them downwards.
- Using position relative on the popout will make it leave empty space where it would have been in the sidebar.
- Floating it messes up the width of other sidebar elements.

The sidebar is fixed width. The popout is fixed-height. The buttons are fixed-size. The sidebar elements are full-width but variable-height.

I've lost track of all the different things I've tried. My closest attempt at the moment is in this [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cUceH/2/), where the popout is positioned correctly, but does not grow leftwards, only overflow downwards. If I set the width to a large number, it will line the buttons up correctly, but it makes strange things happen if I add a :hover pseudo-class.

How could this be done in HTML/CSS? Or is it only possible using JavaScript? If so, what could be a simple "out-of-the-way" approach of doing this?

Comment: There is a JsFiddle linked. Perhaps it's hard to find: http://jsfiddle.net/cUceH/2/

Comment: sorry i was mistaken .but have you tried to solve your problem with the help of firebug

Comment: try adding heights or max-heights to the divs that are having their context wrapped. the popout, by the way, is not fixed height - you only gave it a min-height.

Comment: also, try removing the left div and tinker a bit. I have a feeling that you might have inadvertently positioned elements in a way that restricts the width of your popout from growing any more.

Comment: @Mayankswami how can Firebug help solve this? I thought it was for JavaScript. It appears I was mistaken; thanks for the tip, I'll give it a shot.

Comment: @ZacharyKniebel The popout and popout-item both have a height set (maybe you didn't see it because I put that on the same line as the right/width property?) Only the div.item preceded by div.popout has a min-height; I couldn't set a height generally because it's supposed to be variable.
I hope the left div doesn't affect it, I need it for some other content...

Comment: You're right - sorry about that. I have tinkered with it a bit and I can tell you that there is no really good way to do what you're looking to do in a way that is good coding practice and doesn't use JavaScript. If you would like a javascript solution, I will give you a jQuery one, but your best bet is really to find a pre-styled and cleaned plugin for it

Comment: If nothing can be found, I guess I'll use javascript to set the width of the div - afterall, at runtime I'll know how many buttons there will be, and those are all fixed size. I'm already using jQuery, great lib :)

But I'd really prefer a pure CSS solution.

Comment: Yeah, I know what you mean. CSS is always faster than JavaScript. The good thing about using JS for this though is that you will have a lot more flexibility with your popouts. You could implement the popout purely in css IF you want to define the coordinates, positioning and dimensions of all of your popout elements and sub-elements directly. But the code would be rough and not at all adaptable.

Answer (score 0):

Add `white-space:nowrap;` to `div.popout`.

This will prevent line breaks between the buttons.